# Can I use windows event log to debug an application?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

My application crashes and generates a windows event log that says:

> Faulting application someapp.exe,
>   version 1.0.0.0, faulting module
>   TAOd.dll, version 1.6.9.0, fault
>   address 0x0000f8286.

Is there a way to map this address to a method call?

I don't have debug information. The app is running on a production machine, so it can't be stopped whenever I want.

I would like to find a clue where to start with so few information...

Comment: Can you at least configure the production machine to collect a crash dump automatically?

Comment: I would suggest that you see about getting a test machine and try to recreate the problem there. Whenever possible, try and keep your development code off of your production machine(s). I understand that this is not always possible, but it would allow you to do better debugging/testing.

Comment: If it's your application, that is, you wrote/have the source code, you should be able to add some details to the event log messages that the application generates.

Comment: yes, I could do it, but I'm not sure how often the crash happens

Comment: @Will, I fully agree with you, but my test machine works OK.

Comment: @Will, I can't replace the binary, not at this moment. All I have right now is the event log...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way.  Generate a map file and look up the function.

Edit: Try http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/mapfile.aspx

Comment: @pcent:  Pleasure :)  Be warned its nto easy debugging using a map file but once you have the hang of it it is quite the most useful debugging technique to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, but you have to gather clue.

TOAd.dll is crashing at a specific address?  is it always the same ?

But it'll be better if you use a debugger to get a stack trace, but you also have to get the corresponding TAOd.pdb.

Answer (score 0):

> 0x0000f8286
>   It's RVA, so you can load you dll in debugger or disassembler, go there and look where is it.